# Gear menu - switch account doesn't work

Tags: 13.10, users, accounts

Running Ubuntu 13.10.

I open the gear menu, and see a list of users. Clicking on them does nothing. Shouldn't it allow me to switch accounts?

Follow up: If I am logged in as a user that doesn't have a password set, and I want to switch to a different user (without log out), it seems that I don't have a way to do this. The "Lock/Switch account" just causes the screen to go black for a second and then back in to the current user.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is impossible. When you try to switch user from the drop-down menu in the gear indicator on the menu bar, the system needs to authenticate the user's identity and right to perform the action. It does so in a way that ultimately relies on the information in `/etc/passwd`.

This fails since the user does not have a password set and returns you to the current user. You may be able to switch the user by different means that use a different internal process, but it may be easiest to set a password for the user in question.